# Creating array out of list in tcl

Tags: arrays, list, tcl

Hi i have a list of parent-child items as follows :

```
set mylist {{1:0 2:0} {2:0 3:0} {3:0 4:0} {3:0 5:0} {3:0 6:0} {3:0 7:0}
            {4:0 8:0} {5:0 9:0} {4:0 10:0} {5:0 11:0}};
```

Now i am trying to achieve couple of tasks here.

1. Create a new list of unique items from the above list $mylist.
2. Create an array with keys as the unique items from my newlist and values as some data that i have available.

So i created a new list using the below code.

```
set newlist [list];
foreach item $mylist {
  lappend newlist [lindex $item 0]; 
  lappend newlist [lindex $item 1]; 
}
```

which gave me output as

```
1:0 2:0 2:0 3:0 3:0 4:0 3:0 5:0 3:0 6:0 3:0 7:0 4:0 8:0 5:0 9:0 4:0 10:0 5:0 11:0
```

and then i did lsort -unique

```
set newlist [lsort -unique $newlist];
```

which gave me the unique list `1:0 10:0 11:0 2:0 3:0 4:0 5:0 6:0 7:0 8:0 9:0`

Now I create the array as below

```
array set newarr {
  [lindex $newlist 0] {list of values} 
  [lindex $newlist 1] {list of values} 
  [lindex $newlist 2] {list of values} 
  [lindex $newlist 3] {list of values} 
  ...
}
```

Which basically gives me what I wanted to achieve, but I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same task. For example, I was thinking if there is a better way of creating newlist from mylist, basically the unique newlist from mylist items??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head I might have written something like:

```
foreach item [lsort -unique [concat {*}$mylist]] {
    set newarr($item) {list of values}
}
```

Or you might prefer some variables rather than the nested commands.

Answer (score 1):

Using an array directly is another way to get a list of unique values (cannot have duplicate array keys)

```
% foreach pair $mylist {lassign $pair x y; incr ary($x); incr ary($y)}
% parray ary
ary(10:0) = 1
ary(11:0) = 1
ary(1:0)  = 1
ary(2:0)  = 2
ary(3:0)  = 5
ary(4:0)  = 3
ary(5:0)  = 3
ary(6:0)  = 1
ary(7:0)  = 1
ary(8:0)  = 1
ary(9:0)  = 1
```

You can reassign the array values as you wish.